# Are there any parallel Russian / Slavonic – English prayer books for Orthodox Christians?

Tags: prayer, eastern-orthodox, liturgy, resource-request, prayer-book

I have a copy of [the Jordanville prayer book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/088465074X) that is getting worn out, and I would like to know if a parallel Russian (i.e., Church Slavonic—Russians call it "Russian") and English prayer book exists, particularly one containing morning and evening prayers, prayers before Communion, and possibly some of the other wealth of the Jordanville prayer book.

Simply put: Are there any Orthodox prayer books that are parallel Russian-English and offer similar features as the Jordanville prayer book?

For what it's worth, I searched both Google and Amazon for any prayer books at all with Russian and English parallel. Try searching the topic—it's dry. There is an Old Believer prayer book according to the Old Rite that offers parallel Slavonic and English; beyond that I have yet to find a second.

---

For those not familiar with Orthodox and Old Believers, there is a comparison somewhat like the comparison to be made between Mennonites and Amish. Historically, Old Believers distinguished themselves (the loose Protestant analogue would be the Article By Which the Church Stands or Falls) by adamant persistence in the old arrangement of fingers in crossing oneself when there was historically a change in properly Orthodox practice, and dug in enough to make a separate community; there are or have been Old Believer communities in Latin America that have been persistently unchanged enough that they are more like 19th century Russia than anyone but Old Believers in Russia.

Comment: @David, were you saying that there are too many possible answers, or that good answers would be too long for this format? I've searched, and I fail to see either condition remotely holding true in this particular "put on hold as too broad."

Comment: See http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  Key part: "All answers equally valid".  If you can find a way to phrase it so that it's not likely to get equally valid answers if you get more than one, you're covered.  I also answered more fully in the Meta post.  Thank you for asking, by the way!  I'm glad you cared enough to ask.

Comment: Thank you. I've raised a note about improving the UX at the main meta, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265961/can-put-on-hold-reasons-be-set-to-pinpoint-instead-of-giving-an-overall-ballpa

Comment: There is what looks like a decent version at http://tinyurl.com/russian-english-svit. Some people have said the English translation leaves something to be desired, but it is decent, even if the Jordanville prayer book (http://tinyurl.com/jordanville-prayer-book) offers a better English translation. I am using the SVIT now.

Comment: Jonathan, I've updated your question to make it fit better here.  If it is reopened, feel free to convert your most recent comment into an answer, especially if you can give more details on it.